# Alignment of elements within tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, alignment, linguistics

I am trying to represent the prosodic tones of an utterance but I'm failing to align some elements which should be aligned.

Here's the minimal working example of what I'm doing:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\eabox{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix [matrix of nodes, inner sep=.25ex, ampersand replacement=\&, row 1/.style={font=\itshape}]
        {
            {\normalfont [}uma \& vez \& chegada{\normalfont ]\textsubscript{IP}} \& {\normalfont [}a \& dançarina \& começou \& o \& espetáculo{\normalfont ]\textsubscript{IP}\footnotemark} \\
            \& \& $^*$ \& \& \& \& \& $^*$ \\
            \& \& L$^*$+H H\% \& \& \& \& \& H+L$^*$L\%\\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

And this is the result I get:

[image]

How can I align the asterisks with each other and also add some space between both IP's so that the end of "L*+H H%" doesn't overlap with the beginning of the second IP?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Done, changed it. Is this enough?

Comment: It looks fine now.

Comment: Actually, it's still not an MWE.

Comment: As a general rule, test your example first :) In this case, the result is an error message saying that `\eabox` is undefined, so that needs to be fixed. Either add the definition/package or remove `\eabox` altogether, if it's not relevant to the question. You also forgot `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Before going any further, is this the expected result?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641975/alignment-of-elements-within-tikzpicture
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    %
    \newlength{\mylength}%
    \newcommand{\mot}[2]{#2\tikz[remember picture]\coordinate(#1);}
    \newcommand{\dessous}[3]{%
    \settowidth{\mylength}{#2}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,node distance=1ex,inner sep=0ex,outer sep=0pt]
        \node (d_1)[below=of #1,xshift=-0.5\mylength]{$*$};
        \node [below=of d_1]{#3};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    %
    \begin{document}
    [\textit{uma vez \mot{A}{chagada}}]\textsubscript{IP}\qquad
    [\textit{a dançarina começou o \mot{B}{espetáculo}}]\textsubscript{IP}

    \dessous{A}{chagada}{L$^*$+H H\%}
    \dessous{B}{espetáculo}{H+L$^*$L\%}
    \end{document}
```

[image]